# How to install a project from github based on yii

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components

I'm a newbie studying how it works YII. I found this project interesting.

`Yii2-simple-classified` with `app-advanced`

```
https://github.com/deviardn/diadoo
```

I read the documentation but I do not know exactly what I should do to be able to test it on localhost.

I already have YII2 installed with composer.

what should I do?

Thanks for your kind recommendations.

Comment: Never vote down questions from newbies. This is not a good sign of helping community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The project looks new, the author should explain more. In general, usually I clone the project first

```
$ git clone https://github.com/deviardn/diadoo.git .
```

Install the project with composer

```
$ composer update // or install
```

Initiate the code with this command, and set it to Development

```
$ ./init
```

Initiate the database migration, if necessary

```
$ ./yii migrate
```

And lastly, give it a try from your browser, access the localhost.